# Async method in an ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to use a third-party library in a ASP.NET web forms app.

The third-party method I have to use is an async one.

Since I have to call it in a page click event handler, I have 2 options:

1. Declare every page that has to use this method as <%@ Page Async="true" ... %>
2. Invoke the method synchronously.

**FIRST QUESTION**

Does it make sense to declare all the website pages async only for this method (potentially can be invoked on every page)?

**SECOND QUESTION**

The second question is about invoking the async method synchronously.

Having to invoke the following method

```
async Task<bool> MyMethodAsync()
{
    ...
}
```

Which is the difference between the next 3 invocations?

```
Task.Run(async () => await MyMethodAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
MyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I cannot see any difference during execution…

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Task.Run(async () => await MyMethodAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

This starts a task to run on a threadpool thread that runs the method asynchronously. Then the main thread sits there and waits for the threadpool thread task to finish.

> `Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

This is the same as above, but the main function "continues" before the method fully completes.

> `MyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

This at least avoids using an extra thread to stall the main thread anyway.

Edit: I didn't see this question:

> Does it make sense to declare all the website pages async only for this method (potentially can be invoked on every page)?

Depends what kind of `async`. If they'd still return void, you're gaining nothing, you're just breaking your code base. If you're returning an actual `Task`, then sure. In fact that's how ASP.Net Core works.